# Is there a way to subscribe to VSCode extension update install event?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to run a callback when user is installing VSCode extension update?

In my case it is needed to rewrite an `svg` file that comes with extension and is configured in extension settings (we allow user to change gutter icon color in settings).

When extension update is installed - that `svg` file gets overwritten. So what I want to do is - I want to rewrite that file again with a color from settings. This is by now mean the best approach but it is the only one I could make work as of now =)

Comment: Use the `globalStorageUri` and `globalState` from the `ExtensionContext` and keep track of the version used the previous time  https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext

Comment: @rioV8 thank you! Am I right that this can be used also as a persistent storage for extension files? so that I can actually store my icon file in there and it will persist between extension updates?

Comment: I have no idea, I had read about this extension storage somewhere, not used it yet, looks like it is persistent